# Obtaining variance decomposition table with categorical variables in the model in R

Tags: r

I am running a multiple regression with the code:

```
model = lm(Price ~ factor(Make) + Cylinder + Liter + Doors + Cruise + Sound +leather, data=kuiper)
```

I got the `summary(model)` output without any error.

I am able to get the output of variance decomposition table when I use the categorical variables in the model, but I am not able to produce the output for variance decomposition table (VD Table) using the `colldiag` function in package `perturb` when I have categorical variables in the model.

R is throwing the following error:

```
print(colldiag(model)) 
Error in v^2 : non-numeric argument to binary operator
```

Is there any alternative R code for producing the variance decomposition table for categorical variables?

Comment: When you use a function from a non-default package, please state which package you're using. Some function names occur in more than one package. Are you using the `perturb` package?

Comment: Yes Sir,i am using perturb package.I badly need the output of variance decomposition table when categorical variables used in the model.Please suggest me any alternative code for this.

Answer (score 1):

This post is about a year old now. But I also had this problem and I'm posting the answer just in case others could use it.

Passing a `model.matrix` object seemed to work in my case:

```
cd <- colldiag(model.matrix(model))
print(cd)
```